# Connecting to database over a network using a IP address

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

Please I have a little issue with an application I am developing. I developed the application so that another system can connect to it vi a network. The connected system should be able to access the database of the application from the other system. the application is developed in C# and uses SQL server as database. I want the application installed on two system with one of the systems hosting the database and the other accessing it over the network. Below is a my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="NewConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLSERVER;AttachDbFilename=C:\Hospital\HospitalDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True; User Instance = False"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

please any help wll be deeply appreciated .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your connection string specifies that DB engine should attach a local database file, rather than connect to remote server.

See [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) to find suitable connection string for your purpose.

Comment: I really appreciate your response. Please, am a bit confused as to how to go about it. How do you think it should be done. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it depends on what your remote database is, authentication method it is configured for, protocol type enabled, etc.  If it is SQL Server, it may be as simple as `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;`.  But how to go about it: get the information about your remote db server, then look up on the site connection strings, and try one by one (adapting as necessary such as username or password, or address) by replacing `connectionString` attribute in your question.